# OS X server 4.0, Xcode 6 CI remote repository issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, repository, continuous-integration

Is there an option to add remote repository in Xcode server 4.0?
After clicking on + button, I only get the option to add new local repo.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That feature is gone it seems. Was looking for it as well, but it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @vburojevic Can you elaborate on this please? I couldn't get it to connect to GitLab (also on the local machine where the Xcode server resides)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out as well. The important thing is, that the feature is now basically moved to Xcode, and away from the server. If the repo is checked out in Xcode from some other git host than Xcode server, then the bot will know about it and the server will check out from that source as well when integrating.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Remote repository is handled automatically by server when you create a bot via Xcode.